# Auto correlational of a unit pulse function.

Tags: integration, convolution, correlation

$$
p(t)=\begin{cases}
0& t<0\\\\
1& 0<t<1\\\\
0& t>1
\end{cases}$$

I need to compute $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(\tau) p(t+\tau) d \tau$$

My thinking is :

First convert the integral to

$$ \int_{0}^{1}  p(t+\tau) d \tau$$

because $p(\tau)$ is none zero only when $ 0< \tau < 1 $ and in that interval $p(\tau)=1$

Now I set $x = t+\tau $ and have $$ \int_{t}^{1+t}  p(x) dx $$

Taking $ -1<t<0$ I have $$ \int_{0}^{1+t}  1 dx = 1+t$$
and $ 0< t < 1 $  I have  $$ \int_{t}^{1}  1 dx = 1-t $$

So it looks like my solution is linear with $t$ on those ranges. Does it make sense ? Did I missed something here ?